# Compilation stops without any error for caption.tex

Tags: compiling

I know that we can directly compile `.dtx` files to get PDF documentations. The following experiment is just out of curiosity.

By using the Python script tool [dtx2tex](https://github.com/SwitWu/dtx2tex), one can strip the documentation lines from the `.dtx` file to obtain a corresponding `.tex` file. Experiments for `geometry.dtx` and `fancyhdr.dtx` are just fine since I can compile the `.tex` files from them without any problems.

However, when I use `dtx2tex.py` to process `caption.dtx`, getting `caption.tex` which is to be compiled. A strange phenomenon occurs, the compilation (using terminal) stops in the last without rasing any errors.

Can someone help me to have a look at what's the problem?

Comment: If I ignore the checksum error I get a pdf file as expected

Comment: OK, I’ll check that@DavidCarlisle

Comment: it's not clear why you would ever need this, dtx files often have complicated conditional logic to extract different versions and processing with latex will produce the intended result, this python filter may or may not, depending

Comment: I need to extract the tex file so that I can use the lwarp package which is a pkg converting tex to HTML. I plan to do some relevant conversion project@DavidCarlisle

Comment: why can't you run lwarp directly on the dtx??

Comment: lwarp doesn’t support dtx.

Comment: It may need a bit of customation, but should work